# Trying to do a simple sql insert from one table to another but unfamiliar with terminology?

Tags: sqlite

I have spent the morning learning SQL from scratch but I'm struggling trying to do this **simple** thing and I don't even know what to call it (some kinda insert join?)

I have two tables that look like this...

```
Table: ImageIDLookup           Table: ImagesTable

   ID | ImageID                    Id   | Path
   21 |   147                     147   |  fu
   42 |   268                     268   |  bar
   53 |   547                     547   |  bla
     etc...                           etc...
```

All I want to do is insert the *'Path'* column from **ImagesTable** table into the **ImageIDLookup** table using the column in both tables called *'ImageID'* and *'Id'*, which have matching rows.

So the **ImageIDLookup** table would turn into...

```
Table: ImageIDLookup     

   ID | ImageID | Path
   21 |   147   |  fu
   42 |   268   |  bar
   53 |   547   |  bla
         etc...
```

I realize this is basic, but I'm finding it hard to research simple concepts when I don't have a name for them.

Comment: You're not trying to *insert* anything.  You're altering a table to add a column, then updating the records in that table to put a value in that column.

Comment: https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a new column to `ImageIDLookup`:

```
ALTER TABLE ImageIDLookup ADD COLUMN Path TEXT;
```

Second, add Path values from the `ImagesTable` to `ImageIDLookup`:

```
UPDATE ImageIDLookup
SET Path =
    (SELECT Path FROM ImagesTable
     WHERE ImagesTable.Id = ImageIDLookup.ImageID);
```

On MySQL you can also do second step as follows:

```
UPDATE ImageIDLookup
INNER JOIN ImagesTable ON ImageIDLookup.ImageID = ImagesTable.Id
SET ImageIDLookup.Path = ImagesTable.Path;
```

Comment: Altered the table but the UPDATE code is throwing a "syntax error near INNER". I double-checked all your spelling and the only thing wrong was .ImageId should have been .ImageID. I don't need quotes anywhere, do I?

Comment: Soryy, I meant I fixed your typo, but I'm still getting a 'syntax error near INNER'. Could anything else be wrong?

Comment: Which DB are you using? At least it works in mysql: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5397c4

Comment: Oh, I'm using SQLite. Sorry, does that make a difference to all this?

Comment: I'm using SQLite Manager and it can generate some UPDATE boilerplate and it uses square brackets like this... 

UPDATE tableName SET assignment [, assignment]* [WHERE expr]

Comment: @AzzyDude, I've updated the answer, now it should work for SQLite. Initially, I used UPDATE + JOIN syntax which apparently only MySQL supports.